# What driver to use with a keyboard that has the wrong vendor/product ID?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, kernel-modules, udev, hid

So, I recently bought a new mechanical keyboard, and I've been having trouble with the F1-F12 keys. After some investigation, I discovered that this is happening because the keyboard, for some ungodly reason, has the same vendor ID and product ID as a completely different keyboard manufactured by Apple. My kernel then loads the `hid_apple` driver automatically, which causes the F1-F12 keys to function as they would on an Apple keyboard, which is not what I want.

I have tried remapping the keys using both `xmodmap` and an `hwdb` entry, with no luck. I also tried blacklisting the `hid_apple` kernel module, which prevents the keyboard from working at all. I want to force the keyboard to use the `hid_generic` driver, but I'm not sure how. Is there a way I can force that driver to be used, perhaps through a `udev` rule or similar?

UPDATE:
It turns out that the `hid_generic` driver does not work. Preventing `hid_apple` from being loaded simply stops the keyboard from being recognized.

Comment: You probably just need to change `fnmode` of the `hid_apple` module, like so: `echo 2 | sudo tee -a  /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode`. See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/7553